# MSBUILD Error: VS2015 Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

To keep it simple, I am getting this error on build (release) of an App I'm trying to release.

```
Could not initialize class sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher
```

Google is not helping out, as it looks like I am the only one with this problem.

Regards

Comment: Could you please give some information about what plugins you are using and post some codes to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: I just randomly tried to release it and it worked. Changed not a single line of code. I guess it was a random thing. Though I would like to add that I did reboot and still it didn't work at first. After a day of staying turned off, it worked.

Comment: Just to add more. The app worked in debug mode.